# html css code is not displaying correct design

Tags: html, css

I created this HTML

```css
body{
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0px;
}

.circle{
    background-color: white;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;    
    left: 40%;
    top: 40%;
}
.wing1,.wing2,.wing3{
    background-color: white;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.wing1{
    top: 45%;
    left: 43%;
}
.wing2{
    top: 34%;
    left: 40.2%;
}
.wing3{
    top: 45%;
    left: 38%;
}
.innercircle1-1,.innercircle2-1,.innercircle3-1,{
    background-color: red;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Fidget Spinner Animation</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fidgetspinner.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="wing1">
            <div class="innercircle1-1"></div>
            <div class="innercircle1-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wing2">
            <div class="innercircle2-1"></div>
            <div class="innercircle2-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wing3">
            <div class="innercircle3-1"></div>
            <div class="innercircle3-2"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Those circle,wing1, wing2, wing3 div tags are working perfectly but the innercricle1-1,innercircle2-1,innercircle3-1 are not working.

Don't know what's the problem. can anyone of you help me in figuring what's the problem is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you forgot to remove "," in the end

```
.innercircle1-1, .innercircle2-1, .innercircle3-1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove a comma after this:

`.innercircle1-1,.innercircle2-1,.innercircle3-1`

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you grouped all the innercircles class bt atlast yoy have give the comma also ,for that reason css is not working.

```css
body{
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0px;
}

.circle{
    background-color: white;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;    
    left: 40%;
    top: 40%;
}
.wing1,.wing2,.wing3{
    background-color: white;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.wing1{
    top: 45%;
    left: 43%;
}
.wing2{
    top: 34%;
    left: 40.2%;
}
.wing3{
    top: 45%;
    left: 38%;
}
.innercircle1-1,
.innercircle2-1,
.innercircle3-1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="wing1">
            <div class="innercircle1-1"></div>
            <div class="innercircle1-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wing2">
            <div class="innercircle2-1"></div>
            <div class="innercircle2-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wing3">
            <div class="innercircle3-1"></div>
            <div class="innercircle3-2"></div>
        </div>
```